# Is there any record about installed plugins in the WordPress database?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I want to know which plugin is the last installed plugin. is there any solution for getting information about plugin with query in WordPress database?

I have tried the following query and found something, is there anything more clear?

```
SELECT  * FROM `wp_options`
where option_name LIKE '%plugin%';
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to query all the plugins installed on your Wordpress you may use:

```
$all_plugins = get_plugins();
```

If you need to query only active plugins, you may use:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins'
```

Comment: thanks @Shahin . but your query is  like same as told, is there more info in another table or different field?

Comment: @Aa.mbi, the installed plugins are determined with the files on the plugins folder, not with a record on the DB